# How to get “Final Countdown” Spell card in Duel Links?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I am new to Yugioh Duel Links game and am wondering how to get Final Countdown.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this answer's writing,

## Final Countdown is not obtainable in Duel Links.

To verify this, you can search for it within the **View/Convert Cards** section of the Deck Studio. Doing a text search for the word "final" shows six cards - none of which are Final Countdown.

Moreover, according to the [Yu-Gi-Oh! wiki](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Skill), neither  does a skill which adds Final Countdown to a player's hand or deck currently exist.